# Apache seeing all incoming connection as 192.168.0.1

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

As mentioned, apache thinks that all my incoming connection is 192.168.0.1 (my router gateway).

I am currently running a website through wamp, apache 2.4 with mod_remoteip enabled. However, it does not solve my issue. The website in question is (tsu.myftp.org)

Kindly advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your router port forward may be doing that? if it works why do you really need to change it?

Comment: all my incoming connections are 192.168.0.1
The main problem is that I run a game server. If everyone has the same IP, I cant Ban anyone -.- They cant vote for my server either.

Comment: ok, makes sense, do you have another router you could try? also you might try plugging your server directly into your internet feed bypassing the router completely.

Comment: I upgraded to fibre network recently, my second router configs get forwarded to the main one, which practically renders it useless. Additionally, I cant shift my pc towards the modem as it is 2 floors below my studio -.-

Comment: that's your problem right there. You need to change your first router to be a switch so that your second router gets a public ip.

Comment: So this problem is definitely caused by my router?

Comment: its caused by the fact that you have 2 routers.. the first router takes your public ip and hands out local ip's to all who connect to it (192.168.1.---) because your second router is connected to the first router it receives a local ip that's why i suggested logging into your first router and making it a switch (bridge) so that instead of giving out local ip's it simply directs all of the traffic through it.....